# Is the quotient of separated presheaves separated?

Tags: sheaf-theory, presheaves

Let $X$ be a topological space. If $A \leq B$ are Abelian group-valued sheaves on $X$, then the presheaf quotient $U \mapsto B(U)/A(U)$ is a separated presheaf.

Does this still hold if we require $A$ and $B$ only to be separated presheaves?

I believe the answer is "no". In this case, could you please provide a counterexample?

Comment: Please add your own attempts to answer your question to the question body using the "Edit" button below the question body (in particular why you believe that the answer is "no"). Otherwise you will receive poor feedback and the question will be eventually closed. Thanks and good luck with your question!

Comment: @Matija I tried the obvious approach, it did not work. I had no other attempts, but I googled the question to no avail. I don't think that in such cases I need to elaborate (why annoy others with trivial calculations). I do think, however, that closing the question was uncalled for.

Comment: I did not vote to close the question, I tried to prevent it. And I'm glad Daniel could help you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious proof I can think of for the original statement will still work only assuming $A$ is a sheaf, and $B$ is a separated presheaf.  More generally, it will work if $A$ is a closed subpresheaf of $B$ (where this means that whenever $x \in B(U)$ and we have a open cover $\{ V_i \mid i \in I \}$ of $U$ such that $x |_{V_i} \in A(V_i)$ for each $i$, then $x \in A(U)$).  (Note that we have the general result that if $A$ is a subpresheaf of $B$, $A$ is a sheaf, and $B$ is separated, then $A$ is closed in $B$; the straightforward proof of this fact might very well have been implicit in the proof of the statement you started out with.)

Thus, for a counterexample where $A$ and $B$ are separated, we will need a situation where $A$ is not closed in $B$.  For one such counterexample, let us suppose $X = \mathbb{R}$, and we take $B$ to be the constant presheaf $\mathbb{Z}$, while $A$ is the subpresheaf $\mathbb{Z}_{(-\infty, 1)} + \mathbb{Z}_{(-1, \infty)}$.  To be more explicit, this is the subpresheaf where $n \in \mathbb{Z} = B(U)$ is in $A(U)$ if and only if either $n = 0$, $U \subseteq (-\infty, 1)$, or $U \subseteq (-1, \infty)$.  Now for example consider the global sections $1, 0 \in B(\mathbb{R})$.  Then $\bar 1 |_{(-\infty, 1)} = \bar 0 |_{(-\infty, 1)} \in (B /_{psh} A)(-\infty, 1)$ and $\bar 1 |_{(-1, \infty)} = \bar 0 |_{(-1, \infty)}$; however, $\bar 1 \ne \bar 0 \in (B /_{psh} A)(\mathbb{R})$.

(You might even see a way to generalize the above argument to a converse of the above observations: if $B /_{psh} A$ is separated, then necessarily $A$ must be closed in $B$.)

Comment: Thank you Daniel, that's really nice!